# Autocomplete libraries for Java, C, PHP?

Tags: autocomplete, plugins

I'm building an open-source autocomplete plugin for my text editor because it doesn't have one yet. Are there any autocomplete libraries I can use i.e. some sort of data file containing commonly used functions in Java, C, PHP etc?

I have the plugin built, but I don't particularly want to go through all of Java's documentation and hand-write the actual library that the plugin would reference. I'm just looking for a text file that contains something like:

String
double
boolean
implements
..etc etc etc...

I'm sure someone has solved this problem before. Are there some simple text files somewhere containing common functions/tokens that I could use?

Comment: I could not figure that out by myself, are looking for one implemented in java, c or php?

Comment: I'm not looking for an implementation at all; just a simple data file (.txt, .rtf etc).

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but ctags is your first friend here. Just a quick first step to get you going.

Comment: This was pretty cool, but not exactly what I was looking for...because of the nature of ctags, it is more useful for creating a map of a file than for creating a library of tokens from the file.